# Running wiringPi-python hardware PWM withoot root

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, pwm, wiringpi

I am attempting to run `wiringpi` to control the hardware PWM on GPIO 18 on the pi. If I use `wiringPiSetupGpio()` as below and I run as root everything works. Using `wiringPiSetupSys()` as documentation suggests does not work, even when ran as root.

```
import wiringpi
wiringpi.wiringPiSetupGpio() #must use with root access
#wiringpi.wiringPiSetupSys() #can use without root, does not work

wiringpi.pinMode(18,2)
wiringpi.pwmWrite(18,500) # dim led
```

In order to use the non root method I have exported pin 18 as out and verified it with `gpio exports`. Can I not use hardware pwm without root or am I missing a fundamental step?

Comment: something to do with user permissions?

Comment: @Noelkd I think so. It's a common issue on all Raspberry Pis because the GPIO device is pretty locked down per default

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue in the docs

> This function is not able to control the Pi’s on-board PWM when in Sys mode.